# Postgresql timestamp and future default values in HSQLDB

Tags: postgresql, hsqldb

I'm working with a legacy postgres db that uses column definitions as follows:

```
timestamp without time zone default (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
```

and

```
timestamp without time zone default (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' + 30 * interval '1 day')
```

Unfortunately these cannot be changed.
The goal of the latter one is that the default value is 30 days in the future.
I'm trying to add a modern day junit test framework using hsqldb on top of it.

To bring this in line with hsqldb, the first definition needed to be changed to:

```
timestamp without time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL '0:00' HOUR TO MINUTE
```

However, try as I may, I cannot figure out a way to replicate the column with the addition of the 30 days

Comment: Using a different DBMS for testing than in production isn't a really good idea. One recent example of what can go wrong is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28553532/330315

Comment: I agree with you, however, in this case, the situation dictates it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TRIGGER for this kind of default value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT ON the_table
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
   SET newrow.the_column = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL '0:00' HOUR TO MINUTE + INTERVAL '30' DAY;
END
```

Update: PostgreSQL compatibility has been extended to accept values in the future. Example

```
timestamp without time zone default (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL '0:00' HOUR TO MINUTE + INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

Comment: Oddly, HSQL Database Manager barfs on the opening parenthesis for `expires timestamp(0) with time zone default (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL '0:00' HOUR TO MINUTE + INTERVAL 1 hour) not null`.

Comment: Thank. The Postgres style default worked in version 2.3.3 but not in later versions, due to some code changes. Will be supported again in the next release.